# Запись кадров с графических приложений C++

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, opencv, directx

Все современные графические приложения пишутся с помощью API directX или OpenGL, используя технологию двойной буферизации. На фронт буфере показывается сцена, в бэк буфере она рисуется. К тому же отрисовка сцен происходит зачастую на графическом процессоре видеокарты. Чтобы получить кадр нужно изрядно потанцевать с бубном, например заинжектить DLL в процесс, вычислить адреса функций где рисуется сцена, установить на них хуки используя так называемые батуты, и ещё передать потом этот кадр в другой процесс из бэк буфера. Задача нетривиальная и много низкоуровневой работы, да ещё и нужно знать API dx и ogl. Вопрос такой: а есть ли всему этому альтернативы? Ну в 21 веке все таки живем, я не знаю, может та же OpenCV как то проще это умеет делать из коробки?

Comment: OBS как-то обходится без этого. Начиная с Win10 вообще без проблем любое окно, а в Win7 только при включенном aero.

Comment: Desktop duplication API.